# Authlogic secure and httponly cookies patch

Tags: security, cookies, authlogic, httponly, ruby-on-rails-2

I've been trying to apply the [gist provided in the issue tracker](https://gist.github.com/719669) to add the secure and httponly options and methods on Authlogic cookies, but I'm having some difficulty.  I applied the patch and have gotten the new attributes to show up in my cookies, and I'd like for them to be set by default, so I tried to set them using the second approach suggested in the patch comments using

```
   class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
     httponly true
     secure true
   end
```

However, Rails complains that the 'httponly' and 'secure' methods don't exist.  From the comments it doesn't appear that anyone else is having this problem, and I haven't been able to find any other documentation on this. Am I missing something?